How do I convert word files to pdf in Next.js using an API route
I have checked many npm packages like, mammoth, docx-pdf etc.
But it is converting only .docx file to pdf but I want to convert all the word document file to PDF and want to send the pdf file back in API response.
is there any way to achive this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
